# Azure text to speech API returns audio in byte format with missing characters �

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

We are calling the Azure text-to-speech API with some test text. During testing in python with Jupyter Notebook, the API returns the audio in byte string successfully:

> b'\xff\xf3H\xc4\x00\x00\x00\x03H\x00\x00\x00\x00\x9c\xe7\xb0 \x14\x12E\x03\x0b\xa3\xd5\x02\x84\x89\x85\t-\x1bt@I`\x00\x10\xa1\xf0\xfb\x90\x8a\x1c\x14\x9c\xefi\tS\xff\xfc\x8d\xff\xff\xff\xfc\x8d#N\x7fO\xff\xf9?\xff\xffS\xbf\xeas\xce\xf2T\xe7\x9c\xf22\x9c\xf3\x9eF\x9c\xf3\xbc\x8d9\xe7y\x1as\xce\xe8FS\x9d\

However, when we try to incorporate this into out application, where we do the call using JavaScript, the response looks like this:

> ��H�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003H\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\b\u0001b4���,C�4�\�S$�N��a\u0002И\f�\f\u0013\u0010�Z\u0002�2\u0016H�\u00008G�\u0003\u00156� 8Y 1Sx�0 �lm!\u0016Vh,&\u0000\u0005��i��M|�D�\fU\u000f�,&2\u000e4k\r��_��\u0010Xɓ\u000f�\u0013+MT<���"�&&�3�58&r�x�\r\u0010[�N!49f��Hă\u0018����\u0018F���n�K�\u000b4��3�B�,2n}\tX�Ze�$�\u0004�\u0007�\u0014�ܡ4\u001f4����a�\u0016�{�\u001b*\u0001�QJ�

It looks like there is something wrong with the encoding...? I think the string is being converted to unicode. This should not happen, we need the string as it is returned by the API.

Answer (score 0):

The response you've provided appears to be binary data or a binary stream representing the generated audio from the Azure Text-to-Speech API. To handle and play this audio in JavaScript, you need to convert it to a format that can be played by the browser's audio player, such as an audio file like WAV or MP3.

Here's how you can modify your JavaScript code to handle the binary response and play the audio:

```js
    // Get your Azure Text-to-Speech API key and endpoint URL from your Azure portal.
    const apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
    const endpoint = 'YOUR_ENDPOINT_URL';
    
    document.getElementById('convertButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
        const inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    
        fetch(`${endpoint}/cognitiveservices/v1`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml',
            },
            body: `<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'>
                        <voice name='en-US-AriaRUS'>
                            ${inputText}
                        </voice>
                    </speak>`,
        })
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer()) // Convert response to ArrayBuffer
        .then(arrayBuffer => {
            const audioBlob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'audio/mpeg' }); // Modify the type based on your actual audio format
            const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
            const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
            audioPlayer.src = audioUrl;
            audioPlayer.style.display = 'block';
            audioPlayer.play(); // Play the audio
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
```

**Result**
[image]
In this code, I did following:

1. Convert the response to an `ArrayBuffer` to work with binary data.
2. Create a `Blob` from the `ArrayBuffer` and specify the appropriate audio MIME type. You should adjust the MIME type based on the actual format of the audio returned by the API.

**Another  possible solution**

Use  `speakTextAsync`  from  `SpeechSynthesizer`  that outputs a  `ArrayBuffer`  in JavaScript that outputs binary data.

Below is a sample code snippet that you can refer:

```js
import { SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat, SpeechConfig, AudioConfig, SpeechSynthesizer } from "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk";

const speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("KEY", "REGION");
speechConfig.speechSynthesisOutputFormat = SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat.Audio24Khz160KBitRateMonoMp3;
const audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput("output.mp3");

const synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
    "A simple test to write to a file.",
    result => {
        if (result) {
            console.log("Output string:", result.audioData);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        }
        synthesizer.close();
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error);
        synthesizer.close();
    });
```

The result  `audioData`  is of  `ArrayBuffer`  format that represents binary data.
[image]

For more details regarding end to end text to speech JavaScript application you can refer to this tutorial  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/convert-text-to-speech-cognitive-services).